# Backgroundworker updating log on the ui

Tags: c#, wpf, logging, backgroundworker, ui-thread

I have a wpf application with a text box in the main window that is supposed to be used to display logging information while the user runs a long process.

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,10,10" AcceptsReturn="True" Name="txtLogging" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" 
                 Text="{Binding Path=LogText, Mode=TwoWay}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />

public string LogText
{
    get { return _logText; }
    set
    {
        _logText = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

One of the buttons on the ui kicks off a process that takes a minimum of 30 seconds, and sometimes up to a few hours.  Needless to say, running this on a background worker is preferred.  The issue is that the logging class in the program is being created on the UI thread and has to be accessed during the worker's execution to update the UI with the log of what is currently happening.

The logger looks like this;

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace BatchInvoice
{
    public enum LoggingLevel
    {
        Verbose = 0,
        Info = 1,
        Warning = 2,
        Error = 3
    }
    public sealed class Logger
    {

        string _logFile;
        static Logger() { }
        public bool LogToDataBase = false;
        public bool LogToFile = true;
        public bool LogToScreen = false;
        private Logger()
        {
            //string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            string filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            filePath = filePath + @"\LogFiles";
            string extension = ".log";
            if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
            }
            /*string currentDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(currentDir);
            string fullDirectory = directory.FullName;*/
            string date = (DateTime.Now).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            _logFile = filePath + "\\" + date + extension;
            minimumLoggingLevel = LoggingLevel.Info;
        }
        private LoggingLevel minimumLoggingLevel;
        public static void SetMinimumLoggingLevel(LoggingLevel minimum)
        {
            Instance.minimumLoggingLevel = minimum;
        }
        public static LoggingLevel GetMinimumLoggingLevel()
        {
            return Instance.minimumLoggingLevel;
        }
        private static readonly Logger instance = new Logger();
        public static Logger Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return instance;
            }
        }
        public static void Write(string content)
        {
            using (StreamWriter fileWriter = File.AppendText(Instance._logFile))
            {
                fileWriter.WriteLine(content);
            }
        }
        public static void Write(string content, LoggingLevel warningLevel)
        {
            if (Instance.minimumLoggingLevel <= warningLevel)
            {
                if (Instance.LogToFile)
                {
                    using (StreamWriter fileWriter = File.AppendText(Instance._logFile))
                    {
                        fileWriter.WriteLine(warningLevel.ToString() + ": " + content);
                    }
                }
                if (Instance.LogToScreen)
                    ScreenLogging.Write(content, warningLevel);
                if (Instance.LogToDataBase)
                {
                    //enter database loggign code here.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace BatchInvoice
{
    public class ScreenLogging
    {
        private static ScreenLogging _instance;
        private ScreenLogging() { }
        public static ScreenLogging Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if(_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new ScreenLogging();
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }
        private TextBox _target;
        public static void SetTarget(TextBox target)
        {
            Instance._target = target;
        }
        public static void Write(string content, LoggingLevel warningLevel)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(content, warningLevel.ToString());
            Instance._target.AppendText(warningLevel.ToString() + ": " + content + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

(Yes there is a reason the screenlogging is separated into a different class, but I really hope I don't have to change that)  What can I do to make the calls to this logging class reflect on the UI from within the background worker?  Should I change the LogText property to read from an external file or something along those lines?  Currently I don't have the background worker implemented, so the logging only shows after the task is completed, but I need to be able to monitor its progress while its running.  When I tried putting it into a background worker it errored when it hit a line of code that tried to access the logger.

Comment: You could use Bgworker or Task and update your text box there only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your problem seems to not rewrite all your log calls, I will post another way of doing it, by just changing the ScreenLogging.Write method. I hope that works for you, since you will not need to change your calls to Logger.Write method.

```
public class ScreenLogging
{
    private static ScreenLogging _instance;
    private ScreenLogging() { }
    public static ScreenLogging Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new ScreenLogging();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
    private TextBox _target;
    public static void SetTarget(TextBox target)
    {
        Instance._target = target;
    }
    public static void Write(string content, LoggingLevel warningLevel)
    {
        var appendTextAction = new Action(() =>
        {
            var text = warningLevel.ToString() + ": " + content + "\n";
            Instance._target.AppendText(text);
        });

        // Only the thread that the Dispatcher was created on may access the
        // DispatcherObject directly. To access a DispatcherObject from a 
        // thread other than the thread the DispatcherObject was created on,
        // call Invoke and BeginInvoke on the Dispatcher the DispatcherObject 
        // is associated with.
        // You can set the priority to Background, so you guarantee that your
        // key operations will be processed first, and the screen updating 
        // operations will happen only after those operations are done.
        Instance._target.Dispatcher.Invoke(appendTextAction, 
            DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just changed to this about an hour ago.  I added a lock to the instances of the logger and screenlogging classes, and it seems to be working fine. Thanks!

Comment: Happy you found the solution! Sorry for the delay, I was quite busy and only saw your problem again a bit ago.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are trying to update UI from another thread, you must do it in a special way, where threads must be synchronized to transfer data between the them. In other words, it's like the BackgroundWorker needs to do a pause to update the UI. It can be done using the ProgressChanged event of the BackgroundWorker, and the method ReportProgress. Here is a simple example:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // I guess this is how you are using your logger, right?
        ScreenLogging.SetTarget(this.txtLogging);

        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        // Your classic event to do the background work...
        worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;

        // Here you can sender messages to UI.
        worker.ProgressChanged += Worker_ProgressChanged;

        // Don't forget to turn this property to true.
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        // ReportProgress sends two values to the ProgressChanged method, for the
        // ProgressChangedEventArgs object. The first one is the percentage of the 
        // work, and the second one can be any object that you need to pass to UI.
        // In a simple example, I am passing my log message and just putting 
        // any random value at progress, since it does not matter here.
        worker.ReportProgress(0, "Test!");
    }

    private void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Here you get your UserState object, wich is my string message passed on 
        // with the ReportProgress method above.
        var message = e.UserState as string;

        // Then you call your log as always. Simple, right?
        ScreenLogging.Write(message, LoggingLevel.Info);
    }
```

Comment: This makes sense, but requires rewriting all of calls to the logger that are currently in place.  Those files are also being used in a related commandline application.  Is it possible to detect is a section of code is being run from the main thread or not?  If I could overwrite the Logger.Write() method with something that could check if its being run from a background thread, and if it is, call the report progress method, that would be better.